# mapping complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

From my text book I have this question:

Let f(z)=$\frac{2 z}{z+2}$. Draw two graphs, one in the z-plane and the other showing the image in the w-plane. (You should only need to calculate the images o 0, -2, 2, infinity and -1-i).

c) the line x=y plus infinity
e)the circle with radius 1 centered at 1.

What I have done for c) is to parametrize the line and put it in the function, with the given point I got a rectangle in the w-plane. I dont know if this is correct, there is no solution to the problem (at least I cant find any).

For e) I have written the circle as z=1+$e^{i \theta}$ and used $e^{-i \theta/2}$ to simplify, and the result I got was f(z)= w = $\frac{16 cos(\theta/2)+ 4 sin(\theta/2) i}{12 cos^2(\theta/2)+1}$ after I have rewritten it. From here I dont know what to do. I think I have written f(z) in a bad way.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: This is a Mobius transformation and so it maps lines and circles to lines and circles. In e) the image is bounded so it is a circle. You can look at Conway's book to find out how to find the center and radius.

Comment: In the table of context, I dont see anything relevant to this questions (in that book). I think I need some procedure on how to solve these problems.

Comment: You are right. Contents page strangely does not mention Mobius transformations. In my (Indian) edition of the book this is done in Proposition 3.10. Theorem 3.14 states that Mobius transformations map circles to circles. Incidentally, these question involve heavy computations so I suggest looking at the book instead of trying to work it out yourself.

Comment: In what chapter do you find prop.3.10, theorem 3.14?

Comment: See the chapter on "Elementary Properties and Examples of Analytic Functions". The last section in this chapter has Mobius transformations.

Comment: Thank you for the help.